# Sharepoint 2010 list permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on a branding site that allows anonymous users. By default it allows read access too all lists and libraries.

There are a few forms that gather information, and I want to allow anonymous users to add data, but they should not be able to view the list. I don't see any concept of 'deny' permissions.

This doesn't apply to all lists, just a few.

How is this done?

Thanks.

**Edit**

hmm, looks like on publishing sites that anonymous access to the forms sections is disabled by default.

http:///Lists//AllItems.aspx gives me a 401 unauthorized. That's good! Any danger here that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the list also, you can break inheritence on the list and assign custom permissions

Comment: Looks like you can't separate view/insert, however. Looks like lists forms are hidden by default with publishing templates.